# Sorting in ServiceNow - First by priority and then by updated Timestamp

Tags: sorting, filter, servicenow

In a list view of the incident table in service now, I can easily sort by any given column. If I Filter my Incidents by priority and show only the "high" and "very high" open incidents I can sort that by priority. But unfortunately I didn't find a way to sort first by priority and then by updated. Meaning first I get the very high incidents ordered by the updated timestamp and then the high incidents by priority.

Is that possible to do? I would like to have this ordering in a report which I send out as .pdf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this easily in List view.

1. Select the filter.
2. Click on 'Add Sort' button. Specify 'Priority' and 'a to z'.
3. Click on 'Add Sort' button. Specify 'Updated' and 'a to z'.

Comment: Thank  you sir, how could I have missed that.